# r interpret string as list element

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generate a bunch of graphs and write them into a list variable, something like the following.

```
graphsListHolder <- list()
```

loop around the following code for as many plots as I make

```
filename <- paste some elements together to create a unique name
graphsListHolder[[filename]] <- p # p is the name of the ggplot plot
```

I save graphsListHolder as a `.rds` file.

Later I want to read in the res file, choose from plots in the graphsListHolder file and display with `grid.arrange`. I can hardcode the plot number and the following example works fine when run, plotting two graphs, one on top of the other.

```
grid.arrange(
  graphsListHolder[[3]], graphsListHolder[[5]]
)
```

But if I construct a character variable `temp` like this (or variations on this)

```
temp <- "graphsListHolder[[3]], graphsListHolder[[5]]"
```

and change the grid.arrange code to

```
grid.arrange(
      temp
    )
```

I get

```
Error in gList(list("graphsListHolder[[3]], graphsListHolder[[5]]", wrapvp = list( : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
In addition: Warning message:
In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
```

I also tried `eval(parse(text = temp)` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to choose them, but say you had a vector of the elements you wanted

```
x <- c(3,5)
```

Then you could do

```
grid.arrange(grobs=graphsListHolder[x])
```

Trying to turn arbitrary strings into executable code usually isn't a good idea. Often there are more "traditional" alternatives in R.

For example

```
graphsListHolder<-Map(function(x) {
    ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=x*1:10)) + geom_point(aes(x,y)) + ggtitle(x)}, 1:5)
x <- c(3,5)
grid.arrange(grobs=graphsListHolder[x])
```